# What is the maximum integral value that can be exactly represented by a double?

Tags: r

I want to represent large integers exactly.  What range of integral values can be exactly represented by a double?

Answer (score 2):

If your machine uses IEEE doubles, the mantissa is 52 bits.
The leading `1` is implied.  All-bits-one in the mantissa can therefore
represent the value `(2^53)-1` (with the appropriate exponent).
However, any power of 2 (up to a limit of about +- 1023) can also be exactly represented, and `2^53` is
a power of 2.

This is shown in R with by the value `.Machine$double.digits` (53 on my machine),
the number of (base-2) digits in the mantissa, including the implied leading `1`.

Thus, the largest integer value that can be exactly represented is
`2^.Machine$double.digits` and the smallest is the negation of this value.

A demonstration:

```
2^.Machine$double.digits - 0:5
## [1] 9007199254740992 9007199254740991 9007199254740990 9007199254740989 9007199254740988 9007199254740987
2^.Machine$double.digits + 0:5
## [1] 9007199254740992 9007199254740992 9007199254740994 9007199254740996 9007199254740996 9007199254740996

- 2^.Machine$double.digits + 0:5
## [1] -9007199254740992 -9007199254740991 -9007199254740990 -9007199254740989 -9007199254740988 -9007199254740987
- 2^.Machine$double.digits - 0:5
## [1] -9007199254740992 -9007199254740992 -9007199254740994 -9007199254740996 -9007199254740996 -9007199254740996
```