# Donot want large numbers to be rounded off in R

Tags: r, console, rounding, numeric

```
options(scipen=999)
```

625075741017804800

625075741017804806

When I type the above in the R console, I get the same output for the two numbers listed above. The output being: 625075741017804800

How do I avoid that?

Comment: This number is outside the range of an integer in R. The [largest possible value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988485/what-is-the-maximum-integral-value-that-can-be-exactly-represented-by-a-double) is two-digits shorter. Do you really need it to be numeric? Can you store it as a character value?

Comment: Thanks. Thats the other alternative, but was wondering if there was another way around.

Comment: if one of the answers below solved your problem you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept (whichever one was most useful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use package `Rmpfr` for arbitrary precision

```
dig <- mpfr("625075741017804806")
print(dig, 18)
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  60   bits 
# [1] 6.25075741017804806e17
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I work around the exponential here? I generally type options(scipen=999) whenever I donot want the exponential. That does not seem to work here.

Comment: @boY just do `options(scipen=0)`

Comment: Or if you are dealing with integers, `gmp::as.bigz("625075741017804806")` will display the complete number without using exponential notation.

Answer (score 6):

Numbers greater than 2^53 are not going to be unambiguously stored in the R numeric classed vectors. There was a recent change to allow integer storage in the numeric abscissa, however your number is larger that that increased capacity for precision:

```
625075741017804806 > 2^53
[1] TRUE
```

Prior to that change integers could only be stored up to `Machine$integer.max` == 2147483647. Numbers larger than that value get silently coerced to 'numeric' class. You will either need to work with them using character values or install a package that is capable of achieving arbitrary precision. `Rmpfr` and `gmp` are two that come to mind.